# How to get a nested object within an array using $meteor.object?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

**Data**

```
countries: [
  {
    id: 'qwe123rty456',
    name: 'Australia',
    regions: [
      {
        id: 'poi098uyt765',
        name: 'Western Australia'
      },
      {
        id: '123poi098qwe',
        name: 'Queensland'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**I can get a specific country with the following:**

```
$scope.country = $meteor.object(Countries, $stateParams.countryId);
```

**But how can I get a specific region instead? Such as:**

```
{id: '123poi098qwe', name: 'Queensland'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$meteor.object` [accepts only MongoDB objects](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/meteorObject) as a first parameter. You may try to loop your result to find the inner regions as:

```
$scope.country = $meteor.object(Countries, $stateParams.countryId);

$scope.objectFindByKey(array, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] === value) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$scope.region = $scope.objectFindByKey($scope.country["regions"], "id", "your_id");
```

Or try to fetch your MongoDb collection using Meteor's [core driver](http://docs.meteor.com/?__hstc=219992390.8ff092c1aced7d9f442ba551a5e968a4.1448205253353.1448205253353.1448205253353.1&__hssc=219992390.4.1448205253353&__hsfp=3225843109#/full/find)

Comment: Nope, I get the following error: "The first argument of $meteorObject must be a function or a have a findOne function property."